# How to reconstruct a mesh in Unity with data from STL file

Tags: python, c#, mesh

I'm trying to reconstruct a mesh in Unity with data from an STL file. I tried to parse the STL file using the numpy-stl package in Python and then serialize it to a Json file. In Unity, I wrote a script to deserialize the Json file to reconstruct the mesh, but the mesh is either missing a lot of parts compared to the original model or is just messed up.

I have this python code to parse and store the data from stl file to a json file:

```
mesh_data = mesh.Mesh.from_file(file_path)

a = mesh_data.vectors.reshape(-1, 3)
uq = np.unique(a, axis=0)

vertexDict = {}
vertexList = []

for i, vertex in enumerate(uq): 
    vertex = tuple(vertex)
    vertexDict[vertex] = i
    
    coordinates = {
        "x": float(vertex[0]) / 25,
        "y": float(vertex[1]) / 25,
        "z": float(vertex[2]) / 25
    }

    vertexList.append(coordinates)

triangles = [] 

for facet in mesh_data.vectors: 
    for vertex in facet: 
        triangles.append(vertexDict[tuple(vertex)])

jsonData = {
    "triangles": triangles, 
    "vertices": vertexList
}

with open(json_file_path, "w") as f: 
    json.dump(jsonData, f, indent=4)
```

and then I tried to reconstruct the Mesh in Unity using this script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Linq;

[Serializable]
class TestMeshData
{
    public int[] triangles;
    public Vector3[] vertices; 
}

public class STLParserTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    private string jsonContent;
    public bool DoIt = false;
    private MeshFilter meshFilter;
    private Mesh mesh;
    private MeshRenderer meshRenderer; 

    private void Start()
    {
        meshFilter = GetComponent<MeshFilter>();
        mesh = new Mesh(); 
        meshRenderer = GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        // DoIt is just a variable that I can click in the Unity Editor to start the mesh reconstruction process. 
        if (DoIt)
        {

            jsonContent = File.ReadAllText(@"test.json");

            TestMeshData testMeshData = JsonUtility.FromJson<TestMeshData>(jsonContent);
            mesh.vertices = testMeshData.vertices;
            mesh.triangles = testMeshData.triangles;
            mesh.RecalculateNormals(); 
            mesh.RecalculateBounds();

            Debug.Log(testMeshData.vertices.Length); 
            Debug.Log(testMeshData.triangles.Length);   
            meshFilter.mesh = mesh;

            DoIt = false; 
        }
    }
}
```

I've also tried reading on the coordinate system but I still can't figure out what's wrong. Any help, criticism or advices will be very appreciated, thank you.